Problem with Texture Paint
I'm trying to texture paint an object. When I try to texture paint (with an image or even just a color) I get these lines that don't get painted. What's going on? I'm inexperienced and very new to blender so sorry for the question. Thank you!


Hello could you please pack the image (file > external data > pack resources) and share your file?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

First thing to always remember is to check normals direction of your mesh - any faces pointed the wrong way will not paint except from the other side. Ctrl-N used to be the shortcut in edit mode to recalculate normals.
